# I am so confused about for loops in Java

Tags: java

Recently I tried to write a program that prints out LCM of the two numbers put in parameter.
And although I fortunately do not have any compile errors, I am not getting the right answer.
I used nested ifs in for loop and I couldn't find the problem...can you help me?
I am in overall confused by i++ concept. Thank you.

Here is what I wrote for my LCM class.

```
public class LCM {
    public static int calcLCM(int num1, int num2) { // num1=10, num2=4; their
                                                    // LCM is 20
        // num1 has to be greator than num2
        int multiple = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i == num1; i++) {
            if (num2 == num1) {
                multiple = num2;
            }

            else if (num2 * i > num1) {
                i++;
                num1 = num1 * i;
            }

            else if (num2 * i < num1) {
                i++;
                num2 = num2 * i;
            }

        }
        return multiple;
    }

}
```

Comment: No `main()` for your class?

Comment: You need to have a more thorough, thought out, and researched question in the future. What confuses you **specifically**? Which line number? What statement(s)? Please, help us help you

Answer (score 6):

Change   `for(int i=1;i==num1;i++)` to   `for(int i=1;i<=num1;i++)`.

The `for` loop in your current code  runs only if `i == num1`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
 System.Out.Println(i);
 System.Out.Println("\n");
 }
```

//this loop run 10 times

Answer (score 1):

i++ means, we use the int i as it is in the equation/condition then increment it by one.
for example,

```
int i = 1;
int j = (i++) + 3;
System.out.println(j);
System.out.println(i);
```

The output is

```
4
2
```

j would be 4 because it would use i as it is (1 + 3) then it would increment i so that i would then be 2.

in a for loop there are three parts

> for( part 1; part 2; part 3)

- part 1 is the initial, meaning it only happens once at the beginning
- part 2 is the condition that is checked before every execution. If the condition is true then the code in the body is executed. If false, then it will break out of the loop
- part 3 is the code that executed each time after the code in the body of the loop is executed

Theres a different for loop that can be used for arrays and such with iterators but you'd prob get to it later

Answer (score 0):

The loop will only run if `i==num1` Aka `num1==1`.

Try `for(int i=1;i<=num1;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LCM      
{
public static int calcLCM(int num1, int num2)
{
//num1=10, num2=4; their LCM is 20
//num1 has to be greator than num2
int i=1;
while((num1*i)%num2!=0)
{
i++;
}
return num1*i;
}
```