# For Loop doesn't work

Tags: java, for-loop

I just posted a question about my LCM class and I changed my code but it still doesn't work.
I insert (10,4) so the program should print out 20 but it just prints 0. Maybe there is something wrong on the initialisation? I changed "int multiple" to several different values and the method printed out the value that was initialised to "multiple".
Here is my fixed code. Thank you.

```
public class LCM {
public static int calcLCM(int num1, int num2){ //num1=10, num2=4; their LCM is 20
    //num1 has to be greator than num2
    int multiple=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=num1;i++)
    {
        if(num2==num1)
        {
            multiple=num2;
        }

        else if(num2*i>num1)
        {
            i++;
            num1=num1*i;
        }

        else if(num2*i<num1){
            i++;
            num2=num2*i;
        }
    }
    return multiple;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559367/i-am-so-confused-about-for-loops-in-java) and this one suggest that you need to pick up a programming reference first; spend some time reading before starting to write code.

Comment: So what about the loop isn't working?  It should be iterating just fine (although you will run into a case where you skip values, if `num2 * i < num1`, which may occur often).

Comment: I think there is problem with your algorithm. I don't see clearly what is the algorithm you want to use from your code.

Comment: I dont see any problem with the loop. There must be flaw in the logic within the loop

Comment: In your logic, num2 will never be equal to num1 when input as 10, 4. So multiple will not get new value. so it prints 0. Try to figure out logic to get LCM

Answer (score 0):

You increment `i` inside the loop as well as in the loop condition itself. You don't need that, it will cause your loop to skip values.

Also you are multiplying `num1` and `num2` with `i`. I think what you really want to do is you want to increment them by their original values.

Answer (score 0):

A little change in the algorithm will give right answer-

```
public class LCM   
{  
   public static int calcLCM(int num1, int num2)  
   {   
      //num1=10, num2=4; their LCM is 20  
      //num1 has to be greator than num2  
      int i=1;  
      while((num1*i)%num2!=0)  
      {  
        i++;  
      }  
      return num1*i;  
   }    

       public static void main(String[] args)   
   {  
    System.out.println(calcLCM(10,2));  
   }  
}
```